# Phrase for "the order requires compliance" using the word 'liable"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

'Compliable' is the archaic synonym/form of 'compliant'.  What I am looking for is a phrase to mean *a ruling/order is legally binding to be complied with by a certain date*. All the citations I could find use **liable** for people: people are liable to comply. I couldn't find any citation using *liable* thus: *the **ruling/order/notice/directive** is liable to be complied with*. Using 'must' is an easy choice in this regard, but I'm interested to know if *a thing is liable to be complied with* means *a thing must be complied with*. If this is possible, please give me the link to the citation.

Comment: Is it *the order that must be complied with* or **a person who is liable for compliance** with the order by a certain date. The wording choice seems deliberately vague in "a thing is liable to be complied with" because it leaves out the agent who is liable for complying. Contracts with vague terms can come back to haunt you.

Comment: In what other ways may one write "*is legally binding to be complied with*" ?  How, if at all, may the rewritten phrase incorporate the word *liable*? Please include link to citation.

Comment: OK, let me reiterate: Does " a notice is liable to be complied with " mean " a notice must be complied with " ?

Comment: No, **liable to be** unfortunately is easy to interpret as *very likely to be*, as opposed to *definitely required to be*.

Comment: It is not clear why you would want to squeeze the word *liable* here. Even if it could be done, it would be confusing, given that the word is usually used in such contexts for something else.

Comment: One could be held liable if the order is not complied with...